# How to configure CAS for authenticating proxy ticket

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I have done the setup of CAS as a tomcat webapp in one server. 
I am using this service from another server for validating the user. 
while the service is being called it is generating the ticket successfully and also granting of the ticket happens.

When the ticket is being validated it throws an exception filenotfound. 
Snippet of which is available below.

This is for using CAS from the different server than the one where CAS is configured. 
When I use the CAS and deploy my application in the same server, it works fine. 
It throws filenot found exception when i deploy my application in different server than the CAS's.

This is my spring-security-cas.xml file

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

```
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="${service-url-login}" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
    <property name="authenticateAllArtifacts" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="pgtStorage" />
    <property name="proxyReceptorUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor" />
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource">
            <constructor-arg ref="serviceProperties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="${cas-url-login}" />
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <constructor-arg ref="userService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg value="${cas-url-prefix}" />
            <property name="acceptAnyProxy" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="statelessTicketCache" ref="ehcacheBasedTicketCache" />
    <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
    <property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="simpleAuthorityMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleAuthorityMapper" class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper">
    <property name="defaultAuthority" value="ROLE_NORMAL_USER"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="ROLE_"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcacheBasedTicketCache" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
    <property name="cache">
        <bean class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache" init-method="initialise" destroy-method="dispose">
            <constructor-arg value="casTickets" />
            <constructor-arg value="50" />
            <constructor-arg value="true" />
            <constructor-arg value="false" />
            <constructor-arg value="3600" />
            <constructor-arg value="900" />
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"></bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter" />

<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="${cas-url-logout-service}" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" >
            <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"></property>
            <property name="clearAuthentication" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_logout" />
</bean>

<bean id="pgtStorage" class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl" />
```

This is the error that is being thrown.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://test.nycompany.in/cas/proxyValidate?ticket=ST-10-YA1Eqcdz2lI57fojFazr-&service=https%3A%2F%2Fhub.mycompany.in%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:443)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:270)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://test.mycompany.in/cas/proxyValidate?ticket=ST-10-YA1Eqcdz2lI57fojFazr-&service=https%3A%2F%2Fhub.mycompany.in%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:270)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

I have unset the host.name property in my CAS like host.name=
In order for it to accept request from different domain server.

I expect this to validate the proxy ticket from my application.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The URL in the message after `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException was reachable` from a browser and it was working correctly with CAS 6.0 , logging the user in.

After a few tries I saw that the machine running the application could ping the requested domain, but a `curl` to the whole URL was giving a 404.

So check out the system settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I have done the setup successfully. I don't remember the exact solution now, but basically CAS creates one database. In this database by default only the server in which CAS is running is allowed to make a request. We need to enter the URL pattern from which this request will come to validate the user. E.g. my website URL is : Https://example.com then the entry in the table should be allow: 1, URL: Https://example.com/* where allow and URL is the name of the column. This is the exact solution to it.